# Get distinct current & future weeks number and year from column type varchar()

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a column booking_week in the format WEEKNO-YEAR e.g `20-2018`. Column also contains future weeks `01-2019` or `20-2019` etc.

I need distinct list of current & future weeks so i am using query below but it only returns me for current year. Is there a way to get all future weeks?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(booking_week) as booking_weeks_list 
from bookings 
where booking_week >= date('W-Y', time())
```

I do have a column that has timestamp of booking date but i don't know if that can help?

Comment: Be sure to tag you RDMS

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: MySQL does not allow 2 arguments to `DATE()`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume that `date('W-Y', time())` returns the current week/year.  I don't recognize what database this comes from, but basically you want to do:

```
select distinct booking_week as booking_weeks_list 
from bookings 
where right(booking_week, 4) || '-' || left(booking_week, 2) >= date('Y-W', time())
```

Notes about the solution:

- Not all databases support `left()` and `right()`.  `substr()`/`substring()` can be used instead.
- `||` is the ANSI standard string concatenation operator.  That can also vary by database.
- I don't recognize the formulation `date('Y-W', time())`, but assume it is correct.